# Return the value of testValue after callback is invoked

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback

I am learning some async foundations and callback functions in Javascript 
And I want to return a random boolean after a random delay
I have a function that when invoked returns a callback 
but I don't get how to just return the `testValue` from the callback after the `setTimeout` is resolved.

```
const returnTestValue = () => {
  const delay = 7000 + Math.random() * 7000;
  const testValue = Math.random() > 0.5;

  return callback => {
    window.setTimeout(() => callback(testValue), delay);
  };
};
```

The returned callback after calling `returnTestValue()`

```
callback => {
  window.setTimeout(() => callback(testValue), delay);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. You probably should just take the `callback` as the argument to `returnTestValue`, and not `return` anything (like that function).

Comment: But without changing anything about your code you would do `returnTestValue()(x => console.log(x))`. Note that you cannot actually *return* `testValue` from `returnTestValue`. You may find the following useful even if it doesn't answer your question: https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html

Comment: Btw, you shouldn't use the terminology "return a value" with asynchronous functions - they cannot `return`, the can just call the callback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Bergi Well, technically all functions "return" - - when they are complete they "return" control back to the call stack. And, it's not actually the asynchronous function that calls the callback, it's the asynchronous component that does that (in this case the `window.setTimeout` API). The async function can and does return its data (through the asynchronous API component) to the callback function.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Sorry, I was imprecise myself. I should've written "asynchronous functions cannot `return` *the result*". Of course they need to return control back to their caller before the async callback happens.

Answer (score 0):

You could return a Promise that will resolve with your random boolean after your random delay like so:

```
const returnTestValue = () => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
    const delay = 7000 + Math.random() * 7000;
    const testValue = Math.random() > 0.5;
    setTimeout(() => resolve(testValue), delay);
  });
};
```

and using .then process the result like this:
`returnTestValue().then(testValue => console.log(testValue));`

Comment: You have to pass a function to `setTimeout`. `setTimeout(resolve(testValue), delay);` should be `setTimeout(() => resolve(testValue), delay);`